# When does the date change for the 'visited' badge?

Tags: support, badges

I've been working on the Fanatic badge and had almost 60 days.

Much to my annoyance my count just reset down to one day. I know for a fact that I have been on, albeit sometimes in the middle of the night.

My question is this - how exactly is this calculated and when does the roll occur?

My apologies if this has already been covered - I looked around and didn't find what I was after.

Comment: If you think that's annoying just imagine visiting the site every day for more than a year (my count was over 400 consecutive days at one time), only to find there isn't even a badge for that, which should probably be called something like [get-a-life].

Comment: @JohnGardeniers [tag:creepy-stalker]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Time based badges are based on UTC days.

This happens all the time to people who are not in the GMT time zone. You seem to be in CST. So if you visit Monday around noon, then Tuesday evening, a whole UTC day will have passed between Monday 6pm and Tuesdays 6pm. Same thing happened to me around 90 days.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. Looks like it's time to set up a cron job..

Comment: @TimBrigham That would be cheating.
Now having a cron job remind you to visit the site (or setting it as your phone's homepage or something) is legit.  That's how I got my fanatic badge :-)

Comment: I just put a sticky note on my laptop and visited every night. After I got the badge I made it to ~380 before missing. Funny how when you're not trying it just happens....